# Multiple Insert or Replace Query in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using below query to insert or replace "number" and "time" in "Contacts" table. Is there any way I can insert or replace multiple record in SQLite for Android?

```
"Insert or replace into Contacts (_id, number, status) values ((select _id from Contacts where number = '123456'), '123456','sent');"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database

Comment: @Andrew Fielden, it is for Sqlite not MySql

Comment: @Andrew Fielden, I had already gone through the question but unable to adjust it properly with insert and replace. If you please can give an example of it with insert and replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve speed for Multiple/Batch Database Inserting or Replacing operation using concept of transaction and compileStatement so your query will be compiled only once.

For Example:

```
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
         String sql = "Insert or Replace into Items (itemNumber, description,unitOfMeasure, weight) values(?,?,?,?)";
         ArrayList<ItemMaster> itemsList = // Retrieve your items list here
         for(int i=0;i<itemsList.size();i++)
         {

             SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement(sql);
             insert.bindString(1, item.getItemNumber());
             insert.bindString(2, item.getItemDescription1());
             insert.bindString(3, item.getSellingUOM());
             insert.bindDouble(4, item.getWeight());
             insert.execute();
         }
         db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      db.endTransaction();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your code Patel, but it is a very slow process if you dealing with 100 records for example. I am looking for any quick approach.

Comment: No, I am sure it is not slow. I have done demo to insert 100 records using traditional insert v/s bulk insertion approach. traditional insert takes 1672 ms and bulk insertion takes only 92 ms. look at this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/turbocharge-your-sqlite-inserts-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for insert multiple entries

```
public void insertIntoTable(ArrayList<YourModelClass> alist) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String sql = "insert into tableName (colomname1,colomnname2) values(?,?)";
        db.beginTransaction();
        SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
        for (int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++) {
            stmt.bindString(1, alist.get(i).getMethod1());
            stmt.bindString(2, alist.get(i).getMethod2());
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.clearBindings();
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();

        db.close();
    }
```

Also Make a Model class to specify your variable names.
eg:

```
class ModelClass {

String var1,var2;

public void setVar1(String var1)
{
this.var1=var1;
}

public String getVar1()
{
return var1;
}
public void setVar2(String var2)
{
this.var2=var2;
}

public String getVar2()
{
return var2;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the query, but it looks like you can just update instead of insert or replace (the select will return `null` if number is not found)

```
Update Contacts set status = 'sent' where number in (...)
```

Comment: If there is no record exist then it will fail.

Comment: Which `_id` do you want if it is a new record ? `null` looks very bad

Comment: _id is auto increment, that is why I am not giving any value for _id. + If there is no _id exist for number then it will insert otherwise it will update.